# angular 2 parsing an empty array

Tags: angular

Let me get this straight...

I have an array **frequentClients** that, on its first use, is empty, so there's going to be nothing to iterate through.

but I can't build it like this because ... client.Name doesn't exist??

```
<div ng-if="frequentClients.items.length>0">
    <button 
        (click)="switchClient(client)" 
        *ngFor="let client of frequentClients">
            {{client.Name}}
    </button>
</div>
```

So, even though I've told it not to iterate at all if there's nothing to iterate through, it does it anyway, then throws an error: **Cannot read property 'Name' of null**

What on Earth am I doing wrong here??

Comment: If you are using angular2 shouldn't you use `*ngIf` insted of `ng-if` ?

Comment: Use `*ngIf` instead of `ng-if`. For more information see, [Angular Developer Guide - Template Syntax (ngIf)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif).

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2+ has a very good feature called [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) to handle **null** and **undefined** . It will not throw an error if the client is null or undefined

use **{{client?.Name}}** instead of **{{client.Name}}**

```
<div ng-if="frequentClients.items.length>0">
    <button 
        (click)="switchClient(client)" 
        *ngFor="let client of frequentClients">
            {{client?.Name}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `*ngIf` instead of `ng-if`. For more information see, [Angular Developer Guide - Template Syntax (ngIf)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif).